# GetItemLinqQueryable doesn't return any items

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have two sets of code (below) that fetches items from a container that match conditions specified in "where" statement. One with the sql query works as expected whereas the other with the Linq expressions doesn't. The Linq one would return items if I remove all "Where" statements but what I want is to fetch items matching the conditions in those "Where" statements. Can you help me understand why the Linq one doesn't work?

```
QueryRequestOptions queryRequestOptions = new QueryRequestOptions()
{
MaxItemCount = DefaultPageSize, // 100
};

// THIS CODE WORKS
string query = $"SELECT * FROM root r WHERE r.documentType = @documentType and r._ts > @timestamp";
QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(query);
queryDefinition.WithParameter("@documentType", docType);
queryDefinition.WithParameter("@timestamp", TimestampConverter.ToTimestamp(fromTime));

using (var feedIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<T>(
queryDefinition,
null,
queryRequestOptions))
{
while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
{
FeedResponse<T> feedResponse = await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync(cancellationToken);


// THIS CODE DOESN"T WORK 
using (var feedIterator = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>(false, null, queryRequestOptions)
.Where(d => d.DocumentType == docType)
.Where(d => d.Timestamp > fromTime)
.ToFeedIterator())
{
while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
{
FeedResponse<T> feedResponse = await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: Note: I thought it may have something to do with ".Where(d => d.Timestamp > fromTime)", but removing that where statement didn't help.

Comment: Why not just use the query version? That way you don't run into these issues where LINQ mysteriously doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: I could and that's how i ended up doing it for now. But, i just want to get some insight as to why the Linq version doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your issue has to do with how the linq query in serialized. By default `GetItemLinqQueryable` doesn't use camel case.

You can control the serialization by passing serializing options:

```
container.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>(
    linqSerializerOptions: new CosmosLinqSerializerOptions
    {
        PropertyNamingPolicy = CosmosPropertyNamingPolicy.CamelCase
    });
```

Comment: This was my problem! For some reason the serialization options used to serialize the result objects are different to the ones used to query those objects

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

select many is used wherever i have an array in document

container.GetItemLinqQueryable<>()
.Where(ar => ar.FiscalYear == fiscalYear)
.SelectMany(ar => ar.ResourcePrivileges.Where(arp => arp.ResourceName == accessRequest.PendingUserRequest.ResourcePrivileges.ResourceName)
.SelectMany(rp => rp.Filters.Where(f => (int)f.Role > 2 && subRegionLst.Contains(f.SubRegion) && reqProduct.Contains(f.ProductName)))
.Select(i => new
{
Alias = ar.UserAlias,
Filter = ar.ResourcePrivileges.Where(arp => arp.ResourceName == accessRequest.PendingUserRequest.ResourcePrivileges.ResourceName).SelectMany(x => x.Filters),
})).Distinct();